# ZFS on USB disks isn't mounted on boot

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have a ZRAID on two disks on a disk hub connected to the server via USB 3.0. The system is FreeBSD 10.1.

Now even though the ZRAID gets imported on boot, it doesn't get mounted. I've set a mount point. Whenever the machine is rebooted (which isn't often, but it's still annoying) I have to run `zpool export zraid0 && zpool import zraid0`. It then gets mounted properly, and I have to restart any daemons requiring access to the ZRAID.

How can I fix that mount issue?

Comment: That's not a stable or recommended solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could run `zfs mount -a` from a startup script?

Not that I'd recommend doing ZFS on USB, but hey.